# OneDrive API Sovereign network. Change tracking is not supported against 'microsoft.graph.driveItem'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am testing OneDrive APIs from the China cloud.

Authentication was successful, user discovery works fine, but tracking drive changes does not seem to work.

https://microsoftgraph.chinacloudapi.cn/v1.0/users/(user_UPN)/drive/root/delta

> Bad Request Message: {   "error": {
>       "code": "BadRequest",
>       "message": "Unsupported request: Change tracking is not supported against 'microsoft.graph.driveItem'.",
>       "innerError": {
>         "request-id": "1643c13e-4067-4230-8287-f321ca4bf017",
>         "date": "2020-01-22T15:17:16"
>       }   } } 3436  9     01/22 16:17:16 2841762 ### * - ErrorInfo Json parse error : {   "error": {
>       "code": "BadRequest",
>       "message": "Unsupported request: Change tracking is not supported against 'microsoft.graph.driveItem'.",
>       "innerError": {
>         "request-id": "1643c13e-4067-4230-8287-f321ca4bf017",
>         "date": "2020-01-22T15:17:16"
>       }   } } 3436  9     01/22 16:17:16 2841762 ### * - other expcetion for Execute() : {   "error": {
>       "code": "BadRequest",
>       "message": "Unsupported request: Change tracking is not supported against 'microsoft.graph.driveItem'.",
>       "innerError": {
>         "request-id": "1643c13e-4067-4230-8287-f321ca4bf017",
>         "date": "2020-01-22T15:17:16"
>       }   }

1. Is this expected?
2. Is there any list of APIs that are not supported by Sovereign networks?
3. Plans for supporting those missing APIs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a recap of the supported features across different deployments [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments#supported-features). The capability is currently not supported. To request new capabilities in national clouds please use [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com)